# How to link plotly traces for legend and colour selection?

Tags: r, plotly, legend-properties

## Problem

I am migrating a number of `ggplot`/`ggvis` plots to `plotly` in a `shiny` application. There is an issue I've encountered regarding the linking of traces. I want to be able to show/hide traces by `group` on the legend, which is shared between related data frames.

#### Minimal working example

```
# load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(viridis)

# contrived data to represent actual data points
df1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100),
                  y = rnorm(100),
                  group = rep(c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4"), 25))

# contrived data to represent theoretical relationship
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(rep(-2, 4), rep(2, 4)),
                  y = c(seq(1.9, 1, -0.3), seq(-1, -1.9, -0.3)),
                  group = rep(c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4"), 2))

# create plot with scatter and line traces
df1 %>%
  plot_ly(x = x,
          y = y,
          color = group,
          colors = viridis(n_distinct(group)),
          mode = "markers") %>%
  add_trace(x = x,
            y = y,
            color = group,
            colors = viridis(n_distinct(group)),
            mode = "lines",
            data = df2)
```

#### Attempts so far

My online searches and especially reading the [plotly](https://plot.ly/r) documentation have not taken me far.

I can add `showlegend = FALSE` to the second trace. That does go part way to addressing the challenge, however, I still want to show/hide that trace based on the `group` value.

#### Possible solutions

Based on the architecture of `plotly`, it seems that if I could put the scatter and line onto one trace per `group` then I would get the desired behaviour. However, it seems that a trace may only have a single "mode", which is why I've taken the approach that I have.

If I continue down the path I've started, I think I need to somehow trap the "on click" event for the legend and show/hide the `group` traces... but I'm not really sure where to begin with that.

#### Related / Secondary

In my MWE, I have set the `colors` argument to `viridis`. While that is unimportant to the problem, I have not found a way to ensure the colour selection is instead linked to the `group` (i.e. if the trace for `group` on df1 is blue, I want to make the same `group` blue on the trace for df2. If this is non-trivial and warrants a second question (I searched and found no match... possibly because it is trivial and I'm missing something simple), then I'll ask this part separately.

Comment: There's a `legendgroup` attribute that could let you do what you want, but only if you plot each group separately (8 traces, here), which is sort of a pain and not very R-like.

Comment: @alistaire, thank you for pointing me to the `legendgroup` attribute. I'm going to have a play with that to see if I get any traction, however, the number of groups is reactive with shiny so I'm not sure that will be able to provide a solution.

Comment: Since the code for each trace probably won't be too different, you could probably write it programmatically so it repeats as necessary for given inputs.

Comment: Also, `ggplotly` unifies groups by default, if you don't mind the style. Check out `ggplotly(ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, colour = Species)) + geom_point() + geom_line())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Revisiting history for posterity

Several changes to `ggplot2` and `plotly` in the intervening time since this question was first asked. In the current version (4.7.1) there is an argument `legendgroup` that attends to solving the problem.

### Lazy code

Please forgive the minimum effort placed on elegant coding, however, this extension to the MWE demonstrates the ability to show/hide traces by group.

```
df1_G1 <- df1 %>% filter(group == "G1")
df2_G1 <- df2 %>% filter(group == "G1")
df1_G2 <- df1 %>% filter(group == "G2")
df2_G2 <- df2 %>% filter(group == "G2")
df1_G3 <- df1 %>% filter(group == "G3")
df2_G3 <- df2 %>% filter(group == "G3")
df1_G4 <- df1 %>% filter(group == "G4")
df2_G4 <- df2 %>% filter(group == "G4")

plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>%
  add_trace(df1_G1, x = df1_G1$x, y = df1_G1$y, color = I("red"),
            legendgroup = "G1", name = "G1 - scatter") %>%
  add_trace(df2_G1, x = df2_G1$x, y = df2_G1$y, color = I("red"),
            legendgroup = "G1", name = "G1 - line", mode = "lines") %>%
  add_trace(df1_G2, x = df1_G2$x, y = df1_G2$y, color = I("green"), 
            legendgroup = "G2", name = "G2 - scatter") %>%
  add_trace(df2_G2, x = df2_G2$x, y = df2_G2$y, color = I("green"),
            legendgroup = "G2", name = "G2 - line", mode = "lines") %>%
  add_trace(df1_G3, x = df1_G3$x, y = df1_G3$y, color = I("blue"),
            legendgroup = "G3", name = "G3 - scatter") %>%
  add_trace(df2_G3, x = df2_G3$x, y = df2_G3$y, color = I("blue"),
            legendgroup = "G3", name = "G3 - line", mode = "lines") %>%
  add_trace(df1_G4, x = df1_G4$x, y = df1_G4$y, color = I("orange"), 
            legendgroup = "G4", name = "G4 - scatter") %>%
  add_trace(df2_G4, x = df2_G4$x, y = df2_G4$y, color = I("orange"), 
            legendgroup = "G4", name = "G4 - line", mode = "lines")
```

### Sample output

Showing the first group `G1` deselected. Also note that the colours have been made to match between the scatter and line traces for the same group.

[image: grouplegend_example]